# Mutually orthogonality of the wave functions - Armadillo

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this.

So I'm trying to study the orthogonality of the wave function solutions by calculating the Integral of the product of two solutions of different orders m and n. Now I get to the part where I have to do the product of 2 Hermite matrices of different dimensions, which I can't mathematically perform, one being 3x20 and the other one 4x20. Is there a way around this?

```
   arma::mat Orthonormality::gaussHermiteG(int n, int m, arma::mat Z)
{
    Miscellaneous misc;
    Calcul *caln = new Calcul(n,Z);
    Calcul *calm = new Calcul(m,Z);
    double f1;

    arma::mat Hnm;
    arma::mat res;
    f1 = (1 / std::sqrt(std::exp(n * std::log(2)) * misc.factorial(n))) * (1 / std::sqrt(std::exp(m * std::log(2)) * misc.factorial(m))) * std::sqrt(1 / M_PI);
    Hnm = caln->calculPolynomeHermite() % calm->calculPolynomeHermite();
    res = f1 * Hnm;

    return res;

}
```

Here's my function for getting the quadrature. It this the way to prove the orthogonality, or am I doing it wrong?

```
long double Orthonormality::quadrature(int n, int m)
{
    arma::mat gx;   

    arma::mat gauss_point = {{
            -2.453407083009012499038365306336166239661e-1,
            2.453407083009012499038365306336166239661e-1,
            -7.374737285453943587056051442521042290772e-1,
            7.374737285453943587056051442521042290772e-1,
            1.234076215395323007885818346959410229585,
            -1.234076215395323007885818346959410229584,
            -1.738537712116586206780865662136406442958,
            1.738537712116586206780865662136406442953,
            2.254974002089275523082333344734565128082,
            -2.254974002089275523082333344734565128065,
            -2.788806058428130480525033756403185410695,
            2.788806058428130480525033756403185410655,
            3.347854567383216326914924522996463698566,
            -3.347854567383216326914924522996463698495,
            -3.94476404011562521037562880052441180715,
            3.944764040115625210375628800524411807067,
            4.603682449550744273077675248978347585171,
            -4.603682449550744273077675248978347585109,
            5.387480890011232862016900410681120753981,
            -5.387480890011232862016900410681120754003,
        }
    };

    arma::mat gauss_point_weight = {{
            4.622436696006100896503286398612081142142e-1,
            4.622436696006100896503286398612081142142e-1,
            2.866755053628341297196597062280879168236e-1,
            2.866755053628341297196597062280879168236e-1,
            1.090172060200233200137550335354255770852e-1,
            1.090172060200233200137550335354255770846e-1,
            2.481052088746361088216495255894039439922e-2,
            2.481052088746361088216495255894039440028e-2,
            3.24377334223786183218324713235370544232e-3,
            3.243773342237861832183247132353705443042e-3,
            2.283386360163539672571459179634955394906e-4,
            2.283386360163539672571459179634955393512e-4,
            7.802556478532063694145991999647569104495e-6,
            7.802556478532063694145991999647569095955e-6,
            1.086069370769281693999524563447163430255e-7,
            1.086069370769281693999524563447163432688e-7,
            4.399340992273180553628851455467928211995e-10,
            4.399340992273180553628851455467928212879e-10,
            2.229393645534151292522500616029095785758e-13,
            2.22939364553415129252250061602909578525e-13,
        }
    };


    gx = Orthonormality::gaussHermiteG(n, m, gauss_point);

    arma::mat res;
    res = gx * gauss_point_weight.t();
    long double resDouble = res(0, 0);
    return resDouble;
}
```

Here's the Hermite Polynomial function and its output for the 3 an 4 modes:

```
mat Calcul::calculPolynomeHermite(int n_max, mat z)
{   
    mat H(n_max, z.n_elem);

    if (n_max == 0)
    {
        H = z.ones(size(z));
    }

    else
    {
        if (n_max == 1)
        {
            return z.for_each([](arma::mat::elem_type& val)
            {
                val = 2 * val;
            });
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < z.n_elem; ++i)
            {
                H(0, i) = 1;
            }
            rowvec h2 = rowvec(z.n_elem);
            h2 = 2 * z;

            H.row(1) = h2;

            for(int i = 2; i < n_max; i++)
            {
                rowvec hn = rowvec(z.n_elem);
                hn = h2 % H.row(i - 1) - (2 * i) * H.row(i - 2);
                H.row(i) = hn;
            }
        }       
    }
    return H;
}
```

output :

```
H(3,z):
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
   -4.0000   -2.0000         0    2.0000    4.0000
   12.0000         0   -4.0000         0   12.0000

H(4,z):
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
   -4.0000   -2.0000         0    2.0000    4.0000
   12.0000         0   -4.0000         0   12.0000
  -24.0000   12.0000         0  -12.0000   24.0000
```

Comment: why are they of different dimensions?

Comment: @user463035818 Added the output of the Hermite function.

Comment: i think you misunderstood something. If you calculate the next order you just get one more row. And this row is orthogonal to all previous rows, thats why every step is (sloppy speaking) as good as it can be

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand. Is there something I need to change or missing in my code/logic?

Comment: you are comparing the wrong things. Orthogonality doesnt not really make sense between a 3x20 and 4x20 matrix.

Comment: the rows of your matrices are mutually orthogonal, not the two matrices

Comment: Understood. Thank you!